# If $f(x) = 2x^2 -x+2$ find the following $2f(a)$

Tags: calculus

I understand $$f(a) = 2a^2-a+2$$

However, I do not understand why I am allowed to multiply the entire polynomial by $2$. 
$$2f(a) = 2a^2-a+2,$$ so why multiply the polynomial by $2$?

Which will give me $$4a^2-2a+4.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=2x^2-x+2$ then $f(a)=2a^2-a+2$. All I did is change the variable, the function is still the same. Now take $f(a)=2a^2-a+2$ and multiply **both** sides by $2$ to get $$2f(a)=4a^2-2a+4$$ Point is that you can't multiply the $f(a)$ with $2$ and leave the other side unaltered. You must do the same on both sides to ensure the *equality* holds.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I thought since f(x)= y that one was multiplying y by 2. However, you have made it clear to me that the equation requires one to multiply both sides by 2. Okay, got it. Also..if f(-a) why is the answer 2a^2+a+2 and not 2a+a+2- Why do I keep the exponent after I have completed the operation (that is squared the -a which gives one +a). I don't understand how after squaring the variable, the variable still keeps the exponent. Can you explain?

Comment: I think you're confusing what $f(x)$ means. Basically $f(x)$ is just a mathematical expression involving the variable $x$. When you have $f(a)$ all you do is replace all the $x$'s with $a$'s. Now for $f(-a)$ you just replace all the $x$'s in $f(x)=2x^2-x+2$ with $-a$ which then gives you $f(-a)=2(-a)^2-(-a)+2=2a^2+a+2$. Note that $(-a)^2 = (-1 \times a)^2 = (-1)^2(a)^2 = a^2$.

Comment: And btw, squaring the $-a$ doesn't give $a$ as you said in your comment. See the last two lines of my previous comment. :)

Comment: Okay, so one should always treat a negative in front of a variable as a -1? This rule only applies to variables or quantities that involve variables? I.e. (2-x)= -1(x-2)?

Comment: Oh yes a negative in front of a variable is just like multiply the variable with negative one. That's a rule that applies to both 'quantities' like $x-2$ and variables like $x$ and numbers like $-2 = -1 \times 2$

Comment: Once again, thank you for sharing your knowledge on this topic. Nonetheless, f(x) is a function (rule). However, I thought f(x) was also another way of saying y because it is the output of x (the independent variable). Should I not think of it as such? And if that is the case, why do some people say replace f(x) with y. For example, when one is solving a Piece wise function?

Comment: Well for coordinate systems like the good old x-y Cartesian coordinate system, we plot a curve (not always a curve but nonetheless...) that is mathematically written as a relationship between $x$ and $y$, like for example $y=x^2 + 1$. You can similarly write this as $y= \text{some expression of } x$ where that "some expression of $x$ is called $f(x)$ which in this case happens to be $x^2+1$. Now when we write $y=x^2+1$, all the pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy that relationship are plotted and that is what forms a "curve".

Comment: That I guess explains why $y$ and $f(x)$ are interchanged often.